# How to solve OpenSSL 1.0.2 private key being invalid in QT 5.12.2?

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, openssl, qt5

I am trying to generate a self-signed SSL certificate, write the cert and private key to file and lastly load the cert and private key with QT. I have confirmed the key and cert files to be valid with SSL however when I load the key using QSslKey, the object is not valid.

Here is the code for generating the cert and key:

```
void generateCertificateAndPrivateKey(const QString& commonName, const QString& companyName,
                                      const QString& filePath)
{
    unsigned long e = RSA_F4;
    BIGNUM* bne = BN_new();
    RSA* rsa = RSA_new();
    if(!bne || !rsa || !BN_set_word(bne, e) || !RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, 2048, bne, NULL))
    {
        if(bne)
        {
            BN_free(bne);
        }
        
        if(rsa)
        {
            RSA_free(rsa);
        }
        
        std::cout << "Cant generate rsa";
        
        return;
    }

    EVP_PKEY* pKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    if(pKey == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "PKey null on new";
        return;
    }
    
    const int privateKeyOK = EVP_PKEY_assign(pKey, EVP_PKEY_RSA, (reinterpret_cast<char*>(rsa)));
    if(pKey == nullptr || privateKeyOK != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Private key assignment failed!";
        return;
    }
    
    X509* x509Cert = X509_new();
    const int integerSetOK = ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(x509Cert), 1);
    if(integerSetOK != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Integer set failed!";
        return;
    }

    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509Cert), 0);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509Cert), 31536000L);
    const int setPublicKeyOK = X509_set_pubkey(x509Cert, pKey);
    if(setPublicKeyOK != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Setting public key failed!";
        return;
    }

    X509_NAME* name = X509_get_subject_name(x509Cert);

    if(companyName != QString(""))
    {
        char company[20];
        strcpy(company, companyName.toStdString().c_str());
        X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "O", MBSTRING_ASC,
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(company), -1, -1, 0);
        std::cout << "Company: " << company;
    }
    
    if(commonName != QString(""))
    {
        char location[50];
        strcpy(location, commonName.toStdString().c_str());
        X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "CN", MBSTRING_ASC,
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(location), -1, -1, 0);
        std::cout << "Location: " << location;
    }

    const int nameOK = X509_set_issuer_name(x509Cert, name);
    if(nameOK != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Certificate naming failed!";
        return;
    }
    
    const int signOK = X509_sign(x509Cert, pKey, EVP_sha1());
    if(signOK == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Certificate signing failed!";
    }
    
    const int certOK = X509_verify(x509Cert, pKey);
    if(certOK != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Certificate and key pair invalid!";
    }
    
    X509_STORE_CTX* ctx;
    ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
    X509_STORE* store = X509_STORE_new();
    X509_STORE_add_cert(store, x509Cert);
    X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, x509Cert, NULL);
    const int certStatus = X509_verify_cert(ctx);
    if(certStatus != 1)
    {
        std::cout << X509_verify_cert_error_string(ctx->error);
    }

    const int privateKeyStatus = X509_check_private_key(x509Cert, pKey);
    if(privateKeyStatus != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "KEY NOT VALID";
    }
    
    QString keyFilePath;
    if(filePath.endsWith("/"))
    {
        keyFilePath = filePath + m_sslFileBaseName + ".key";
    }
    else
    {
        keyFilePath = filePath + "/" + m_sslFileBaseName + ".key";
    }

    std::cout << keyFilePath;

    FILE* keyFile;
    keyFile = fopen(keyFilePath.toStdString().c_str(), "wb");

    const int keyFileOK = PEM_write_PrivateKey(
        keyFile,            /* write the key to the file we've opened */
        pKey,               /* our key from earlier */
        NULL,               /* default cipher for encrypting the key on disk */
        NULL,               /* passphrase required for decrypting the key on disk */
        0,                  /* length of the passphrase string */
        NULL,               /* callback for requesting a password */
        NULL                /* data to pass to the callback */
    );

    if(keyFileOK != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to write private key";
    }

    QString certFilePath;
    if(filePath.endsWith("/"))
    {
        certFilePath = filePath + m_sslFileBaseName + ".pem";
    }
    else
    {
        certFilePath = filePath + "/" + m_sslFileBaseName + ".pem";
    }
    
    std::cout << certFilePath;

    FILE* certFile;
    certFile = fopen(certFilePath.toStdString().c_str(), "wb");
    
    const int certFileOK = PEM_write_X509(
        certFile,
        x509Cert
    );

    if(certFileOK != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to write certificate";
    }
}
```

And here is the code i use to load the key:

```
QFile qKeyFile(keyFilePath);
if(!QFile::exists(keyFilePath))
{
    std::cout << "Pprivate key file doenst exist!";
}

if(qKeyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QSslKey sslKey = QSslKey(qKeyFile.readAll(), QSsl::KeyAlgorithm::Rsa,
    QSsl::EncodingFormat::Pem, QSsl::PrivateKey);
    if(sslKey.isNull())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load private key from file";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Suceeded to load private key from file";
    }
}
```

No error prints show up except the last one where "sslKey" is null. Is this a version incompatibility or am I doing something wrong in the code even though the key generated is valid? I have tried with different parameters for the QSslKey constructor but nothing works.

Comment: Is the `openssl rsa` command able to read your .pem file? You never seem to `fflush` or `fclose` the file so maybe it is not yet fully written. It is also weird that you go through the trouble of creating an x509 certificate and a keystore and then .. not do anything with them.

Comment: Unrelated: see the `qUtf8Printable` macro to get a `const char *` out of a QString, don't use the SHA1 algorithm for signing certificates, use `QFile` for filename handling.